# Customize colors in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to customize the colors used by VSC background and text? I've tried all the color themes and none gives me what I need to see text clearly and comfortably. I can't find information on this in the Help, in the menus, or by searching on the Web.

Comment: Did you find https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme?

Comment: Thanks, I found Color Customizations / Edit in settings.json / {
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Solarized Light",
    "search.location": "panel"
}. Now what do I do? I don't see any instructions, sorry.

Comment: Look over these examples: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvscode%5D+colorcustomizations

Comment: Searching for "vs code custom color theme" took me directly to the documentation. Another minute or so of clicking around, I found https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme -- the bit you want starts with "To tune the editor's syntax highlighting colors..." and has a handy screenshot.

Comment: Thanks to Mark and Roger. But why are all these just examples? Where is a list of all the properties and values for setting colors? Is the documentation really this partial? Can one find the full list or JSON Schema internally in VSCode? I've posted a github Issue and I'll add any other information I find here.

Answer (score 2):

I found the full list of color settings. I would imagine this would be useful to almost every user. It is at https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color .

Comment: this answer would be better with the list _in the question_ (just in case the link expires)